# How does Infusing work?

Tags: destiny

I'm aware of the general requirements for infusing a piece of gear:

- Target item must have the Infuse perk.
- Sacrificed item must be:

  - Unlocked (available for disassembly)
  - Not equipped
  - Same general type (fit in same gear slot) as the target item
  - Same year as the target item
  - Minimum rarity rating of blue/"Rare"
  - Higher Attack/Defense rating than the target item
- Player must have other required resources (Glimmer, Marks, etc.)

However, I haven't been able to find anything yet on exactly how Infusing works. Particularly I want to know:

1. How much of an increase in Attack/Defense does Infusing grant?
2. Are any other stats increased as well?
3. Do any perks get transferred?
4. Does the amount of difference in Attack/Defense between the two items affect how much of an increase is granted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summarizing data gleaned so far:

> **1. How much of an increase in Attack/Defense does Infusing grant?**

Approximately 80% of the difference between the values of the gear that is used. (See answer to #4 for more detail.)

> **2. Are any other stats increased as well?**

Other stats may get a slight bump, to scale with the gear's quality, but the overall roll won't be substantially changed. Which stats see boosts, and by how much, hasn't been verified.

> **3. Do any perks get transferred?**

No.

> **4. Does the amount of difference in Attack/Defense between the two items affect how much of an increase is granted?**

Yes. The formula is roughly `N = O + ((I - O) * 0.8)`, where:

- N is the new Attack/Defense value for the item being boosted.
- O is the original Attack/Defense value for the item being boosted.
- I is the Attack/Defense value of the item being disassembled for infusion.

Some sort of rounding is done when the formula does not put out a whole number value for N. The rounding logic that is used (or even if the rounding is predictable at all) has not yet been definitively verified.

The minimum boost is 1. Logically, this reduces the likelihood that "round down" is being used since that would require hard-coding the minimum. (Not really a big deal, but probably best to avoid if possible.)

Indeed, some players have reported "round up" being used while others report cases of "round down". This would make "round to nearest" seem to be the most likely candidate, but I personally have had mixed results and haven't been able to nail it down.

Further testing and input would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: Do fully upgraded items give better results when infused? Or isn't it worth upgrading items if you're going to infuse them? Except in the case where upgrades increase the stats of the item to be infused.

Comment: @DavidYell Haven't tested upgrading items before using them for Infusion, but my gut says no. If you get a chance to test it (and a set of gear that matches closely enough to give solid results), I'm definitely interested in hearing what you discover.

Comment: Most of the reading I've done indicates it's a straight up numbers game, so unless upgrading the item provides an attack boost, there's no point.

Answer (score 1):

There's been a lot of discussion and experimentation on this posted on Reddit

Specifically [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/3l74nv/infusion_guide_to_infusing/cv3sj3v)

To answer 1 and 4 here is what the above thread says (paraphrased slightly):

> New Value = Original Value + ((Infuse Target - Original) * 80%)
>   Rounding up where appropriate and with a minimum increase of 1

Comment: I think your formula is missing a parenthesis or something. Based on the OP in that thread, it should be: `New = Original + ((Target - Original)*0.8)` (Probably some extra parenthesis in there, just for clarity.)

Comment: @Iszi Good spot, I just copy pasted direct from original thread, will correct in answer

Comment: To add to this, armor gets stat increases as it is leveled up, and perks are not transferred. Items stay as there are with the exception of the higher attack/defense.

Answer (score 1):

As you play more and more, the value of legendary marks will diminish. With this in mind, it is best to simply give in and upgrade gear as you go instead of hoarding them.

If you plan to save, the best piece to buy with your legendary marks if you are at a low light level is the 280 ghost shell.

Okay, so we are past hoarding and now into spending marks with disregard. In order to maintain a solid piece of legendary gear, it will need to be infused.

Infusing does not change the roll on the gear. Infusing will increase the stats of the gear slightly to scale depending on the increase but will not change the type of stats. Infusing will give roughly 80% (plus rounding, which seems to be normal rounding, so above .5 rounds up, below rounds down, and .5 rounds to the [nearest even number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx) - to note though, .5 is impossible to reach when multiplying a whole number by .8) of the different in light (which is to say that a difference of 100 yields +80).

Infuse often, and make sure that you save some of your higher light blues in order to raise up gear which may be quality but not quite high enough to use.

Exotics can be infused, even with blues. Legendaries can be infused, even with blues (or exotics, or legendaries).

Infusing will open an interface (so you can click it and then look at the interface before use). The interface will hold a set of *that same slot* gear which has a higher light level than the piece to be infused. Then you must hold x on the selected piece to dismantle it (this destroys the other piece) and the upgraded light level is shown once complete.

The only thing that infusing increases is stat numbers and light level.

Comment: Not sure why you say it scales differently based on getting +5 from a diff of 6. 80% of 6 is 4.8. Rounded to the nearest whole number, that's 5 - also (in this case) the same as rounding up to the next whole number. Because Attack/Defense/Light are measured in whole numbers, rounding is a must if you're doing any division or throwing non-whole numbers into multiplication. So, how to round?

Comment: Rounding to the nearest may be "fairest". But you probably want to also ensure that there's a minimum boost of 1. So, you either hard-code the minimum while you round results greater than 1 to the nearest whole number or (what I expect is happening) round all non-whole numbers up to the next whole number. So, where you have a diff of 6 and the multiplier is 80%, we should logically expect the boost to be 5. Are you seeing any different behavior in other infusions?

Comment: @Iszi - I think I may have gotten the whole 6 actually, I will test more tonight. I think even up to a certain number you get 100% may be 9?

Comment: @Iszi - I remember it being more than the 80% + rounding. I removed that part for now until I can verify.

Comment: @Iszi - Okay I tested on several pieces and it is just the flat 80 plus rounding up.

Comment: I tested a few last night and I think I got mixed results on the rounding. Think I'm going to assume 80% rounded down, minimum of 1, and be happy when I get the "1 extra".

Comment: @Iszi - I used a 286, infused it with a 294, and got to 293. That was one of the edge cases I tested.

Comment: Yeah, I don't recall what numbers I used. I just distinctly remember the result coming out rounded down. Still, even without knowing which way it's rounding, just knowing that it's a reliable 80% of the diff gets you close enough to have an idea of what a certain combination will give you. Plus or minus 1 isn't usually a big deal.

Comment: @Iszi - Yeah. I try to do mine in steps, but luckily I reached 299 last night and am just going to hang out in the raid with the 310 drops. Done with worrying about these little +/-1 nuances haha

Comment: Of course, there's always the possibility that it's not actually rounding to whole numbers. Your light level, attack/defense stats, etc. could actually be getting calculated and stored at a higher precision and only displayed as whole numbers. Which is really going to throw off any end-user attempts at trying to nail down the formulas.

Comment: I tapped 280 last night before doing some infusions. Hopefully I'll get into the 290s by the weekend. Then yeah, raids. Maybe we can meet up for one sometime?

Comment: @Iszi - You can add me if you want. I try not to post my gamer tag here on SE so it will be in a temporary image http://i.imgur.com/i1sHa1N.png

Comment: Ran some calculations, because curiosity just won't die. Some of the most interesting edge cases to test would be differences of: 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39. These all come out to numbers ending in .2, when multiplied by 80%, and so they're the most likely to be rounded down if the formula requires it. If those end up rounded down consistently, you can add two to any of them for test cases to verify a "round to nearest" theory. Adding two to those numbers gives you numbers that work out to values ending in .8.

Comment: @Iszi - I will see if I can test those numbers or some of them tonight.

Comment: @Iszi - 9 was 7.

Comment: Thanks for the data point. That's definitely interesting, as it demonstrates a case of rounding down - indicating we could be looking at a "round to nearest" logic instead of the "round up" that everyone has assumed so far.

Comment: @Iszi - Yeah, it doesn't seem to round up in that scenario. To be honest I was a little disappointed because It was from 284 to 293 and I only got to 291.. I felt robbed, I needed that 1 light lol. I edited my post to reflect the rounding issue.

Comment: Come to think of it "round to nearest whole" does just fine for enforcing a minimum of 1 in this case, too. The disassembled item has to be higher than the item being boosted, so you've got a minimum diff of 1. 1 * 0.8 = 0.8; round that to the nearest and you still get 1 for your minimum boost.

Comment: Note: Different rounding mechanisms treat `.5` differently, and we really can't be sure how Destiny's apparent "round to nearest" logic for infusion would behave since it will never see a `.5` so long as the multiplier is 80% and inputs are whole numbers. Possible remainders are `.8`, `.6`, `.4`, `.2`, and `0`.

Comment: @Iszi - Regardless of hitting that exact value, that is where the line is drawn for rounding.

Comment: True, but what's done at that line varies depending on how the algorithm is written. So we can't say whether `.5` would be rounded up or not since we don't have any test cases.

Comment: @Iszi - A remainder of .5 cannot be reached when multiplying a whole number by .8 so it is a moot point ;) Oh, and 4 is 4 (I tried that one too last night). Got my 291 to 295 with a 295.

Comment: That's kind-of what I said already. I was just pointing it out since you did specifically say ".5 and up rounds up" in your answer. Also, Wikipedia has an interesting depth of detail when it comes to the many ways tie-breaking can be done with rounding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking

Comment: @Iszi - Considering that Destiny was more than likely written in c# it is probably using a simple Math.Round in which case it would round as such: "The integer nearest a. If the fractional component of a is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the even number is returned. Note that this method returns a Double instead of an integral type." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx So that would support your case of not always up (even though it cannot be .5 anyway).

Comment: Maybe we should petition Bungie to change the multiplier just so we can have fun testing that theory. ;-) (That said, I wonder what happens if a fractional component of a is halfway between two integers that are either both even or both odd? How would that even happen?)