# Does the quality of the disassembled item affect how Infusion works?

Tags: destiny

Related: [How does Infusing work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236693/how-does-infusing-work)

When performing Infusion, does it matter what the quality is of the item being disassembled for Infusion?

Per answers to the earlier question, it seems the primary thing affected by Infusion is the target item's Attack/Defense value. Other stats on the item aren't significantly changed, except to scale with the Attack/Defense.

The same answers also state that the boost given in Infusion is approximately 80% of the difference (some rounding done) between the Attack/Defense values of the two items involved. However, I'm fairly certain I've had at least a couple cases where Infusion has granted the full difference - even when the 20% I should be missing would be >1 (i.e.: any amount of expected rounding wouldn't account for this).

Could it be that using Exotics for infusion grants a bigger boost (or a chance of getting a bigger boost) than Legendary or Rare items? Is there some small difference between Legendary and Rare as well?

Comment: Note to self: I need to start documenting all my Infusions from now on so I can get a better handle on this.

Comment: I have infused equipment with legendary(purple) equipment and gotten 100% of the difference. I have also gotten 50% of the difference added. I would say it's some RNG here.  
But the only thing on the disassembled item that counts when infused is the attack/defense AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

Infusing any quality item into a legendary(exotic) will give the item 80(70)% of the difference, if it is greater than 6(4). If the difference is 6(4) or lower it will transfer at no loss.

The only other item that can be infused is the common handcannon "Imprecation" which is part of a gunsmith quest. This always takes 50% of the difference.

Answer (score 3):

As of the last update in april,all infusions are 1:1 .

> All roads lead to more powerful gear. New and updated rewards have
>   been added to all high level activities. Infusion now upgrades gear to
>   the existing Light of the consumed item directly.

[bungie](https://www.bungie.net/en/pub/AprilUpdate)